# Aws Spring boot application view issue with jar and rest service issue with war

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to host one application on AWS elastic beanstalk(java). The application has one view and one rest service.  First I uploaded the jar file and tried accessing, the path to view was giving me whitelabel error on AWS but it is working fine locally. Also, am able to access the rest service with jar.

After surfing the net, I created a war and uploaded on AWS(tomcat). Now, the view is working fine but I notice the path of rest service is returning 404.  Can someone suggest what should I check or do?